# struts filterdispatcher 404 error

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, web.xml

(basic struts project using appfuse)- when i configure the web.xml then build & start the server its shows only white spaces. then by using firebug i check the response it's 404 error, again if i remove filterDispatcher(2nd mapping in follows) then its show the starting page. whats wrong any idea?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-cleanup</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.webapp.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-cleanup</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: @which version of S2 are you using and what is the outcome if you are able to use `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`

Answer (score 1):

FilterDispactcher is deprecated use StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And there is a possibility of getting empty page when you are returning result name is null in action.